# Don't enter into database if field is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this piece of code to save an email into our database but if the user doesn't enter an email address then it inserts an empty row... what is the best way to stop this happening?

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

     $query = "INSERT INTO `email_capture` (`email_id`, `email_address`)
              VALUES (NULL, '$email');";

     mysql_query($query);

     echo "";

     mysql_close($email_sql);
}
else {
     mysql_close($email_sql);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `if` statement to:

```
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    // ...
}
```

No need to use `isset()` when using `empty()`.

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: This worked perfectly, I am now also reading into the link you provided! I'm new to PHP and things like this are vital, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't only check if `$_POST['email']` is set, but also check for an empty string:

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']!=""){
//your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Isnt `!empty($_POST['email'])` the same as what you have in the if statement?

Comment: Logically that doesn't make sense though?

Comment: @BradHouston, What doesn't make sense?

Comment: There is no reason to use `isset()` and `empty()` together, PHP's `empty()` function will check if the variable is set and return false if it is not.

Comment: Yes, but my solution is easier to understand (my opinion), as negated statements

Answer (score 0):

You should use `empty()` to check the post

```
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    // ...
}
```

`empty()` will check and return true if the variable is set and not empty. But it will also check for variables like `0` witch `$_POST['email'] !== ''` will not.

Answer (score -1):

Most simple way of doing this is to modify your `html` code just add required attribute to your `html`. Thats it now form won't be submitted unless users types email.

```
<input type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Email"/>
```

Comment: This is not the best way to solve the problem, as it relies on client side validation which isn't backed up by server side validation. The user could still enter an empty email by bypassing the form altogether.

Comment: You don't know how he is posting that, he could also use e.g. AJAX